# Why would humans evolve pointy ears?

Tags: evolution, species

So, I'm creating a world in which there are elves. There is no magic in this world, it's sort of post-apocalyptic. These elves evolved from humans. I'm asking whether or not it's possible for humans to evolve ears like this, and why animals evolved those kinds of ears in real life.

Comment: Pretty sure we already have questions for most of those already. Do a search and see what you can find.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. We observe a strict "one question per post" policy, thus please narrow yours down to fit the policy. But first, as @Halfthawed pointed out, check what has been already asked on some of those races. You can find more info in the [help]

Comment: Thank you for telling me. I'm new to this website, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for editing your question. However, this has already been asked https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/25474/30492

Comment: Thank you for redirecting me. I didn't see that before.